# How to filter specific query results on kibana queries

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have the follow query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "message": {
        "query": "Error",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However I get results with specific content which iam not interested on.

for example:

```
2017-12-05 15:51:54,012 ERROR io.vertx.spi.cluster.zookeeper.ZookeeperClusterManager - Failed to handle memberRemoved
io.vertx.core.VertxException: java.io.InvalidClassException: io.vertx.spi.cluster.zookeeper.impl.ZKSyncMap$KeyValue; local class
```

so i want to upgrade my query not to return results which contain the word: ZookeeperClusterManager

how can I do that with my current query?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) with `must_not` for negative search.

Query should be something like this

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match": {
                    "message": "Error"
                }
            },
            "must_not": {
                "match": {
                    "message": "io.vertx.spi.cluster.zookeeper.ZookeeperClusterManager"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You need to use `io.vertx.spi.cluster.zookeeper.ZookeeperClusterManager` because of how indexing in ES works. ES uses analyzer to turn the long string into a list of values, that it can search on. One of the steps to do that is to split the text by spaces (tokenization). And that's what's happening here.

`2017-12-05 15:51:54,012 ERROR io.vertx.spi.cluster.zookeeper.ZookeeperClusterManager - Failed to handle memberRemoved`

Is converted to the following list

```
2017-12-05
15:51:54,012
ERROR
io.vertx.spi.cluster.zookeeper.ZookeeperClusterManager
-
Failed 
to 
handle 
memberRemoved
```

That is why your search for `error` works, but search for `ZookeeperClusterManager` does not. `ZookeeperClusterManager` on itself is not present in the list. For more information about how analysis works, I suggest you [read this blogpost on ES website](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-text-analysis-part-1). Generally, you could fix this problem by making the tokenizer tokenize by spaces and dots instead of only spaces. How to setup custom analysis is [described in this blogpost](https://tryolabs.com/blog/2015/02/25/elasticsearch-analyzers-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-custom-filters/).

Comment: could you please show me full result using my original query?

Comment: Sorry, can't test it right now, but this should do.

Comment: it didnt work:( still see phrases with ZookeeperClusterManager term

Comment: This could be because in your mapping "message" is not tokenized, or is tokenized only by spaces (not dots). Try replacing it with the full string `io.vertx.spi.cluster.zookeeper.ZookeeperClusterManager`. Does that work?

Comment: I assume, that if you put `ZookeeperClusterManager` in your original query it would not work either ...  (it would not return only items with `ZookeeperClusterManager`)

Comment: you were right with your response - io.vertx.spi.cluster.zookeeper.ZookeeperClusterManager did the trick. can you explain why when you wrote just part of it elasticsearch ignored it?